# does one mine bit coin at current difficulty until next difficulty is set

Tags: difficulty

In Bit coin mining I would like to know if after all 2016 blocks are found and the new difficulty value is set, does one mine continuously on this new difficulty through to the 2016 blocks or does one mine with adjusted difficulty with every block found?

Answer (score 1):

Once the difficulty adjusts, it does not change again until 2016 blocks later.